# Django URL Translation - Stay on the same page when changing language

Tags: django, internationalization, django-urls

I developped a Django app with i18n for urls as well.

That look really nice but when changing the language I would like to stay on the same/previous page.

What is the best way of doing that ?

Basically to get the new url I need to do a `reverse` on the name of the previous page after having changed the language and do a redirect but how can I know the url name of the previous page?

**Edit:**

A solution that came from a collegue:

Calculate a next parameter for each language using request.resolver_match.
   For each language : `activate(language) + reverse('{app_name}:{url_name}', args, kwargs)` using request.resolver_match elements

Do you see a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options for you:

**Option 1**

If you use the `form` from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) then will take you which brings you back to the page you were on.

**Option 2**

When changing the language you could use the referrer header, `HTTP_REFERER` , and redirect back to where you came from

```
# Change the language
# ... code ...

# Redirect back to where we came from
redirect_to = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', reverse('default-redirect-page'))
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

Comment: But as the URL changed the redirect_to HTTP_REFERER will raise a 404 or change your language again.

Comment: Since documentation changed the link for Option 1 is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language.

Answer (score 5):

After change language with django-modeltranslation redirecting to home ?

**If you want to redirect to the same page, you can replace this part of code:**

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
<div class="languages">
<p>{% trans "Language" %}: </p>
  <ul class="languages">
    {% for language in languages %}
      <li>
        <a href="/{{ language.code }}/
          {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
          {{ language.name_local }}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

to:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
<div class="languages">
<p>{% trans "Language" %}: </p>
  <ul class="languages">
    {% for language in languages %}
      <li>
        <a href="/{{ language.code }}/{{request.get_full_path|slice:"4:"}}"
          {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
          {{ language.name_local }}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Attention please:**

> <a href="/{{ language.code }}/

**replaced to** `<a href="/{{ language.code }}/{{request.get_full_path|slice:"4:"}}"`

Comment: this only works if the path has not been translated, otherwise you only change the prefix of the language but keep the rest of the url in the original language, getting a 404